# How to create Cloud Run mapping to wildcard subdomain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, godaddy, wildcard-subdomain, google-cloud-run

I host my app with cloud run and use domain from GoDaddy. It is work perfectly. Now I want to make possible have url address for every users account like user1.myapp.com, user2.myapp.com.
How can I do it with cloud run and GoDaddy?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oR14.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Google Cloud Run you must map a custom domain for each domain name. Wildcards are not supported yet. Since App Engine does support this, I expect that Cloud Run will support wildcards in the future.